# PGAdmin creates new random volume with each "docker-compose up"

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Each time I run the following command:

```
> docker-compose up -d
```

... in a directory where I have the following docker-compose.yaml file, I get a new, randomly named volume.

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  pgadmin:
    restart: always
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-foobar}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-password}
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-8080}:80"
```

**output at command line:**

```
C:\postgres> docker-compose up -d
Creating network "postgres_default" with the default driver
Creating pgadmin_container ... done
C:\postgres> docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               3ee8f970ff477052c6fba9001575a0efa0254deb8dcf73ca97d0422231c74931
C:\postgres> docker-compose down
Stopping pgadmin_container ... done
Removing pgadmin_container ... done
Removing network postgres_default
C:\postgres> docker-compose up -d
Creating network "postgres_default" with the default driver
Creating pgadmin_container ... done
C:\postgres> docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               3ee8f970ff477052c6fba9001575a0efa0254deb8dcf73ca97d0422231c74931
local               705dad9c905eb8f1679a9ee4ff290363c40f5285b8048204cab44bce26916845
C:\postgres>
```

You'll see that where there was one volume with a 64-char name after the first "up", after the second call to "docker-compose up", there were two. This pattern continues.

What is causing the randomly named volumes? How do I prevent their creation of force the system re-use them?

I've actually edited down my docker-compose.yaml file to get to the bare minimum to recreate the problem. There is also, actaully, a Postgres database being started with the same file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you use `docker inspect dpage/pgadmin4` to have a look, you will see next:

```
"Volumes": {
    "/var/lib/pgadmin": {}
},
```

This means in its `Dockerfile`, it defines a `Anonymous volumes` like next:

```
VOLUME ["/var/lib/pgadmin"]
```

Above will make volume name changes every time when you up/down service. To make it not change, you could override it with `Named volumes`, like next:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  pgadmin:
    restart: always
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-foobar}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-password}
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-8080}:80"
    volumes:
      - my-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

volumes:
    my-data:
```

You can refer to [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag) & [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#remove-volumes) to learn more about it.

Comment: Different from the example YAML file I gave in my question, I did actually have a "volumes" section. My problem was that I wasn't specifying the container's directory of "/var/lib/pgadmin", but was rather using something different. In effect, it was the same as not having it.
Thanks for your answer, it has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/) the image creates a volume in:

```
/var/lib/pgadmin
```

> This is the working directory in which pgAdmin stores session data,
>   user files, configuration files, and it's configuration database.
>   Mapping this directory onto the host machine gives you an easy way to
>   maintain configuration between invocations of the container.

A `docker inspect container_id` shows:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "70c8ae8e1de3e5d6c71fa9c63930cc75761132f4fdb75a2982b32454313b78c6",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/70c8ae8e1de3e5d6c71fa9c63930cc75761132f4fdb75a2982b32454313b78c6/_data",
        "Destination": "/var/lib/pgadmin",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
],
```

So it seems that an anonymos volume is created each time 
In order to reuse the volume use `docker-compose start/stop` instead of `docker-compose up/down`.  Similar issue discussed [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/why-are-unnamed-volumes-created-when-docker-compose-up-is-run-and-do-these-dou),

Comment: docker-compose down doesn’t delete volumes by default (ref. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/).

Comment: I think this explains the reason [Preserve volume data when containers are created](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#preserve-volume-data-when-containers-are-created)